# Python logging.get_Logger(name) with FileHandler does not write to file

Tags: python, logging

If I get the logger with a name and add a FileHandler it does not write to the file.

This works and writes correctly to the file:

```
log = logging.getLogger()
fh = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
log.addHandler(fh)
fh_fmt = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s (%(levelname)s)\t: %(message)s")
fh.setFormatter(fh_fmt) 
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

This does not write to the file:

```
log = logging.getLogger(name)
fh = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
log.addHandler(fh)
fh_fmt = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s (%(levelname)s)\t: %(message)s")
fh.setFormatter(fh_fmt) 
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

The only difference is that I get a 'named' logger.

Comment: The code works for me.  What version are you using and do you have file permissions?

Comment: What is the value of 'name' passed to getLogger?

Comment: i have file permissions because the upper code works. the value for name is a string, whatever i set it does not write to the file. im on python 2.6

Comment: You've not shown the code which makes the logging call. Which logger are you logging to? What's its level? Can you update your question to show a complete script which fails?

Comment: there is not much logic there. after setting up the logger i call it like: log.info('the message...')

Comment: so after a while i used another solution to this i tried it again and it magically worked.

Comment: Please share that working solution.

Comment: i've run into the same issue. Explicit writing of name gives me no record neither in the file nor in the console (i have two corresponding handlers). What is the purpose of getLogger's name?

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather old question, but I believe I found the underlying problem and solution, at least with a newer version of Python.

The second code example starts with `log = logging.getLogger(name)`, where `name` is presumed to be a string representing the name of the logger. Since a name is provided, this `log` will **not** be the root logger. According to [Logger.setLevel(level) docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging.Logger.setLevel) for Python 3.6+,

> When a logger is created, the level is set to `NOTSET` (which causes all messages to be processed when the logger is the root logger, or delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger).

This tells us that we have to set the level of our logger so that it will actually process the messages instead of passing it to the root logger.

This is a code example I wrote (in Python 3.7) that does not work:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import logging

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
log_file_dir = Path('./log/')
config_file = 'config_file.txt'
config_file_path = log_file_dir / config_file

logger = logging.getLogger('example_logger')
fh = logging.FileHandler(config_file_path, mode='w')
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.info('Start Configuration Log')
```

And this one works by adding one line:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import logging

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
log_file_dir = Path('./log/')
config_file = 'config_file_2.txt'
config_file_path = log_file_dir / config_file

logger = logging.getLogger('example_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) # <------ Or the applicable level for your use-case
fh = logging.FileHandler(config_file_path, mode='w')
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.info('Start Configuration Log')
```

Note: The first code example does create the chosen log file, but does not write `'Start Configuration Log'` to the file.