# Python logging FileHandler outputting blank file

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to change all my overused prints, to logging.* mainly because i wanted to have a logfile.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter("{levelname}:{name}:{message}", style="{")

file_handler = logging.FileHandler("log.txt")
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Thats the code i have for now, and it's printing to the console correctly but not outputting anything at all to the file. The file even gets created randomly, but but when it does, it's always empty.

I'm using `logger.debug()` and `logger.info()`, not the `logging.*` ones.

#### Update:

Just copying that same code to an empty script, and importing works as expected. Weird.

#### Update 2:

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881411/solved-python-logging-get-loggername-with-filehandler-does-not-write-to-file) that has the same problem as me, he says he found a solution, but he doesn't share it :(

#### Update 3:

This is my [source](http://pastebin.com/JwGBh62G). The code gets called by uTorrent everytime the status of a torrent changes. This is the command i have setup in uTorrent:

```
py C:\Users\Gcq\Downloads\Torrent\torrent.py -n %N -d %D -f %F -p %P -c %S -s %M
```

py because i have  shebang at the top of my script that tells py to use python3. I have python2.7 installed too.
And the the commandline otions are the info that uTorrent exposes.

Comment: what python version/os?

Comment: @IonutHulub Python 3.3.2 [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: Welp, i think i'm not going to get an answer from this...

Comment: Random idea: have you check write permission in the folder?

Comment: @MaximeLorant i think its okay, as i said, the file randomly gets created, so write permission should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought 'okay, i didn't told python where to put my output file' and indeed, it was on uTorrent base folder.

With all the expected output, so everything is working perfect now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce the problem (I have Python 3.3.0 installed rather than 3.3.2, but that shouldn't be relevant. See this screenshot:

[image]

The behaviour seems as expected, so I would look more closely at your Python installation/configuration, or any other part of your actual code which you haven't shown above.

Comment: does the file `log.txt` get created?

Comment: Yes - if you look at the screenshot, you'll see where I do `type log.txt` and that its contents are printed and are as expected.

Comment: oh yeah, i didn't watch carefully.